# parse-php-sdk Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'unauthorized'

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-server

I have double, triple checked the keys, the javascript sdk works great, but when I try to connect with the php sdk, i get Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'unauthorized' when i try to login a user or do anything

```
require ("parse-php-sdk-master/autoload.php");
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize("secret","secret","secret");
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://serveraddress.herokuapp.com','parse');
```

I am using the most recent version of the php-sdk, an alternative server running the javascvript sdk, connects and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the keys are right but you not passing it on the constructor in parse-server. Make sure its in the parse-server config.

You can also try passing your `REST_KEY` in the initialize on both the php client side and through parse-server.

```
 ParseClient::initialize('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_REST_KEY', 'YOUR_MASTER_KEY');
```

**Update for Heroku**:

You need to add all the optional keys: `restAPIKey`, `dotNetKey`, `clientKey`, `javascriptKey`, to index.js as part of the initialization. Then you must set values for ALL of them. If even one of them is not set, `restAPIKey` is not enforced.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
  javascriptKey: process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY || '',  //** add this line no need to set values, they will be overwritten by heroku config vars
  restAPIKey: process.env.REST_API_KEY || '', //** add this line
  dotNetKey: process.env.DOT_NET_KEY || '', //** add this line
  clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY || '', //** add this line
});
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the constructor? i am using herokus parse-server

Comment: @user3634054 in your case you can edit config vars from Settings tab in Heroku Dashboard.

Comment: Where appid is set, you need to make sure in the Heroku setting that you have that other keys there too.

Comment: I have added the JAVASCRIPT_KEY and REST_KEY to the heroku settings.  I also added them to the index file with the link to the server vars.

Comment: So just make sure you set them all in the index.js file and pass the APP, REST, MASTER in php client side. This will work. Heroku will fail otherwise

Comment: oh wow, I didn't see that in the docs anywhere, ok, i will add them all and cross my fingers

Comment: Ya, its not. Lets just say its being alot of trial and error with Heroku